# Понимание Android adapters

Tags: android

Только сделал старт в изучении android. В общих чертах понимаю что adapter - это что-то, промежуточное между моделью и представлением.

Но помогите лучше понять, что это такое и все его возможности и применения.

П.С.
если можно какие-то ресурсы или материалы.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Начнем с того, что `Adapter` это не какой то неведомый абстрактный класс, а один из основных [структурных шаблонов проектирования](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)), который описан и разобран максимально подробно.

в общем случае, назначение адаптера - преобразовать один вид информации в другой, без вмешательства в исходное состояние информации.

Известно, что в ООП всё - объект, парадигма объектно-ориентированного программирования подразумевает, что виртуальная программа устроена так же, как и все, что окружает нас в реальной жизни, поэтому наглядным живым примером адаптера будет, как это ни странно - адаптер, приспособление для соединения не соединяемого, например, переходник SVGA - HDMI для подключения старой видеокарты к новому монитору.

Конкретно в Android паттерн Adapter нашел одно из своих применений в формировании различных списков на экране по имеющимся данным.
То есть, есть какая то структура упорядоченных данных и ее необходимо отобразить на экране устройства. Структура представляет собой какие то цифры, текст и тому подобное, на экране это все должно быть `View` - явная несовместимость между источником и приемником.
Можно решить эту проблему разными способами, например, предварительно преобразовать данные в подходящее для вывода на экран представление, НО! так мы потеряем исходные данные и при каждом изменении данных потребуется новое преобразование, что выглядит очень сомнительно с точки зрения производительности.

Здесь на помощь и приходит адаптер, который стоит посредником между данными и экраном, преобразуя "на лету" данные в `View`, не изменяя первые.

Адаптер ПОСЛЕДОВАТЕЛЬНО берет единицу данных, соответствующюю текущей ЗАТРЕБОВАННОЙ виджетом ПОЗИЦИИ одного из айтемов списка и преобразует эту единицу данных в форму, пригодную для отображения на экране - генерирует `View`. Виджет, отдав адаптеру требуемую позицию, в ответ получает от адаптера визуальное представление, состоящее из помещенных в нем данных и выводит его на экран.

Все возможности и применения адаптеров исходят из вышеизложенного - адаптация одного вида данных к другому. Применение адаптеров, связанных с виджетами, вроде `ListView`, ограничено преобразованием структурированных данных в отображение на экране, но ничто вам не мешает использовать сам паттерн для решения любых аналогичных преобразований и здесь его применение ограничено только вашей фантазией.

Comment: спасибо большое ! Теперь я окончательно все понял.

Answer (score 5):

Adapter это связь вашего View со списком данных вашего класса. Более подробнее почитайте сдесь http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/arrayadapter.php