# Как сохранять состояние чекбоксов в ListView из активити, а не через слушатель в адаптере

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

Объясните по-человечески, почему при скроллинге `ListView` чекбоксы теряют свои положения? Каким образом это можно устранить, если я заблокировал `CheckBox` и слушатель на него мне не нужен?

Класс адаптера...

```
public class InteractiveArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model>
{
private final List<Model> list;
private final Activity context;

public InteractiveArrayAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Model> list) {
super(context, R.layout.row, list);
this.context = context;
this.list = list;
}

static class ViewHolder {
protected TextView text, summ;
protected CheckBox checkbox;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
View view = null;
if (convertView == null) {
LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
viewHolder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ColMemberID);
viewHolder.summ = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ColName);
viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chb_products);
viewHolder.checkbox.setFocusable(false);
viewHolder.checkbox.setClickable(false);

view.setTag(viewHolder);
viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));

} else {
view = convertView;
((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));

}
ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
Model item = list.get(position);
holder.text.setText(item.getName());
holder.summ.setText(item.getBeta());
holder.checkbox.setChecked(item.isSelected());      

return view;
}
}
```

Класс модели...

```
public class Model {

private String name, beta;
private boolean selected;

public Model(String name, String beta, Boolean selected) {
this.name = name;
this.beta = beta;
this.selected = selected;
}

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public String getBeta() {
return beta;
}

public void setBeta(String beta) {
this.beta = beta;
}

public boolean isSelected() {
return selected;
}

public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
this.selected = selected;
}
}
```

Код слушателя нажатий на айтемы ListView...

```
lv_products.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
{
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
{
CheckBox box = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.chb_products);

if(box.isChecked()) {
box.setChecked(false);
mSqLiteDatabase.execSQL("UPDATE products SET complete = '0' WHERE _id=" + position);
}
else {
box.setChecked(true);
mSqLiteDatabase.execSQL("UPDATE products SET complete = '1' WHERE _id=" + position);
}
}
});
```

Как мне быть?

Comment: у вас `item.isSelected()` нигде не меняется

Comment: @metalargus, что вообще делает эта строчка holder.checkbox.setChecked(item.isSelected()); ?

Comment: это ваш код, это я у вас должен спросить, что она делает

Comment: @metalargus, ну, она устанавливает чекбоксам или true или false.......

Comment: @metalargus, значит менять item.isSelected() надо где-то. А мне слушатель на чекбокс не нужен. У меня все происходит при нажатии на айтем ListView

Comment: Если вы добавите код класса-модели и части активити, которая слушает список, то я набросаю приблизительный пример в ответе.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В понимании общего принципа действия и назначении адаптера вам, возможно, поможет [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/491520/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-android-adapters/491568#491568).

Далее, почему состояния чекбоксов изменяются при прокрутке.
При создании текущего айтема адаптер не всегда создает его разметку заново, для ускорения работы он использует уже созданную ранее разметку для айтема, который в настоящее время не видим на экране, так как она идентичная для всех айтемов списка. При этом, если принудительно не заполнять текущий айтем данными в методе `getView()` адаптера, то он берет то, что осталось в прошлый раз в том виде, в каком оно было при последнем (пере)использовании. От этого и появляется эффект, когда виджеты с состояниями произвольно "скачут". Из всего этого в частности следует, что никакие "блокировки" чекбоксов не решат эту проблему, потому что вы просто видите на экране те айтемы, которые находились выше (ниже) по списку и теперь скрылись за границей экрана.

Решение простое. При формировании каждого айтема принудительно устанавливать состояния, соответствующие именно той позиции, которая в данный момент отображается на экране. Для этого эти состояния нужно где то отдельно сохранять. Поскольку вы работаете с классом-моделью и выделили специальное поле для хранения состояния чекбокса, то им и следует пользоваться. При изменении состояния чекбокса (клике на нем или всем айтеме) новое состояние необходимо записывать в модель. Для этого необходимо контролировать нажатия через какой-либо слушатель кликов и все манипуляции проводить в нем.

В вашем же коде **как раз и отсутствует сохранение** изменения состояний при клике. Для решения вашей проблемы, поскольку отдельный слушатель на чекбокс вам не нужен и изменение состояния осуществляется по клику на весь айтем, в адаптере **следует реализовать метод-сеттер**, который будет изменять модель этого адаптера, сохраняя изменившееся состояние. Вызывать этот метод надо будет из активити, при обработке слушателя кликов на списке `OnItemClickListener()`.

Так же стоит предусмотреть возврат измененных состояний из адаптера (метод-геттер), когда все необходимые отметки будут сделаны, поскольку при выходе из активити со списком, адаптер и соответственно модель, переданная в него, будут утрачены и ваши отметки пропадут даром.

Примерная реализация может выглядеть так:

```
public class InteractiveArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {
  private final List<Model> list;
   ...

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ...

   }

   // метод-сеттер для изменения состояния в модели адаптера
   public void setCheckedBox(int position){

    // получаем текущее состояние и инвертируем его
    list.get(position).setSelected(!(list.get(position).isSelected()));
    notifiDataSetChanged(); // перерисовываем список,чтобы применить изменения

   }
}
```

В активити:

```
lv_products.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
{
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
{
CheckBox box = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.chb_products);

if(box.isChecked()) {
box.setChecked(false);
mSqLiteDatabase.execSQL("UPDATE products SET complete = '0' WHERE _id=" + position);
}
else {
box.setChecked(true);
mSqLiteDatabase.execSQL("UPDATE products SET complete = '1' WHERE _id=" + position);
interactiveArrayAdapter.setCheckedBox(position); // изменяем данные в модели адаптера
}
}
});
```

PS

Так же несколько замечаний:

Если вы работаете с БД, то вам лучше всего использовать классы, предназначенные для работы с БД, например `Cursor` и наследоваться от `SimpleCursorAdapter()`, который возвращает ID записей из БД или использовать какую то из ORM.
В частности, сейчас у вас такая ситуация, что вы **пишите в БД по позиции**, но ID в БД **не равен** значению позиции в адаптере, при внесении\удалении данных из БД позиция и ID будут отличатся, поскольку ID всегда присваивается следующим по счету. То есть, удалив третью запись в БД (из, скажем, пяти) вы получите следующую последовательность ID в базе: 0,1,3,4,5, в то время как позиции в списке будут: 0,1,2,3,4. Вы получите ошибку и запишите данные не туда.

Так же рекомендуется сделать класс-враппер для работы с БД, который будет реализовывать методы записи, чтения и тп операции CRUD, а не слать "сырые" запросы, как вы делаете сейчас.

Comment: Стоит заметить, что данный алгоритм хуже классического, с слушателем в адаптере, поэтому автору вопроса все же лучше реализовать свой адаптер по более правильному алгоритму.

Comment: класс враппер для работы с БД у меня есть, просто я не разобрался как отправлять запросы и решил сделать сырой запрос. Я теперь все понял, адаптеры это интересно :) воспользовался вашим кодом, в итоге красным подчеркнулось setCheckedBox с ошибкой 'there is no such reference available here' поменял метод в классе адаптера подписав static, ошибка исчезла, но появились другие, подчеркнулось list. А каким образом можно реализовать стандартный слушатель в адаптера? Если с этим у меня ломается логика в приложении. И насчёт SimpleCursorAdapter - я о нем узнал слишком поздно, ну ладно, переделаю.

Comment: если я поставлю слушатель на чекбокс в самом адаптере, то придётся убирать слушатель для айтемов списка. Если делать слушатель на чекбоксы, то придётся убитать блокировки для них. В итоге я получу возможность чекать только нажатием на чекбокс, а при нажатии на айтем списка он не будет выделяться. Все равно дальше нужно будет сделать показ AlertDialog по долгому тапу на айтем. Именно поэтому я отказался от слушателя в адаптере

Comment: вообщем выделяется красным setCheckedBox с ошибкой 'there is no such reference available here'. Как фикснуть?)

Comment: @СергейГрушин Вы можете повесить слушатель не на сам чекбокс, а на корневой лэйаут разметки (для этого надо присвоить ей id и получить на него ссылку через `findViewById()` ), а в этом слушателе изменять состояние чекбокса через его методы, хотя это будет и не так удобно, как работать с слушателем чекбокса напрямую. По ошибке - вы написали этот метод где то не в том месте, в статическом холдере скорее всего, он должен быть в классе самого адаптера.

Comment: а при замене public на static ошибка пропадает, но list и notifyDataSetChanged(); подчёркивает теперь. ошибки - 'this field can not be referenced from a static-context. одно без другого не работает. Грабли и спереди и сзади...

Comment: уже везде этот метод перетыкал. setCheckedBox также подчёркивает красным с той же ошибкой. нет, в статическом холдере я только объявляю protected-переменные. Метод сеттер у меня отдельно. И в адаптере.

Comment: Киньте полный код адаптера в вопрос (замените тот код адаптера, который там сейчас) я посмотрю сам, потом откат сделаю, чтобы вопрос и ответ не потерял смысла..

Comment: код заменил. P.S. не обращайте внимания что так долго. Вся работа ведётся в телефоне

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39329/discussion-between-pavlofff-and--).

Comment: забыл уточнить. у меня и модель и класс адаптера находятся в разных активностях. То есть, три файла .class

Comment: я написал активность чтобы было понятно..)

Comment: огромное спасибо! теперь чекбоксы сохраняют свои положения при уходе/возвращении на экране :))))

Comment: Еще раз спасибо за помощь со списками, я уже очень сложные списки без проблем делаю, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно в модель записать состояние чекбокса, попробуйте добавить нечто подобное.

```
viewHolder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        list.get(position).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked()); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Из прошлых вопросов этого автора получается, что ему нужно именно то, что сейчас в заголовке, поэтому, к сожалению, ваш ответ в данном случае не подходит, хотя в общем случае он, конечно, правильный.

Comment: @pavlofff, дополнить вопрос моделью и кодом слушателя из активности?

Comment: @pavlofff, добавил. посмотрите пожалуйста