# Проблема с CheckBoxes в GridView

Tags: java, android, checkbox, gridview

У меня есть GridView с фотографиями (фотографии подгружаются в AsyncTask), возле каждой фотографии есть CheckBox, когда юзер ставит галочку в CheckBox, то она отображается не только в той ячейке, где он ее нажал, а еще и в строке, которая находится шестью строками ниже (это видно при скролинге). Не могу понять в чем проблема и как ее решить.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pNI14Zfj_N4&feature=youtu.be

Код Activity:

```
 public class ChooseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private ArrayList listFile;

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.choose_grid);

            Intent intent = getIntent();
            listFile = (ArrayList) intent.getSerializableExtra("LIST_FILES");

            GridChooseAdapter adapter = new GridChooseAdapter(this, listFile);
            GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridChooseView);
            gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
```

Код Адаптера:

```
public class GridChooseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList items;

    public GridChooseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList items) {
        this.items = items;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.choose_item, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            viewHolder.imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }

        else{
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        viewHolder.imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
        File image = new File(String.valueOf(items.get(position)));

        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        final String imageKey = String.valueOf(items.get(position));
            ChooseDownloadTask task = new ChooseDownloadTask(viewHolder.imageView);
            task.execute(imageKey);
        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
    }
}
```

Код AsyncTask:

```
public class ChooseDownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    private final WeakReference<ImageView> viewHolderWeakReference;
    private String data = null;

    private ImageView imageView;

    public ChooseDownloadTask(ImageView imageView) {
        viewHolderWeakReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        data = String.valueOf(params[0]);
        final Bitmap bitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(data, 100, 100);
        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {

        imageView = viewHolderWeakReference.get();

        if (imageView != null) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

xml GridView:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/GridLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#118b0a"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/gridChooseView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:columnWidth="150dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"></GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

xml item в GridView:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop">

    </ImageView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:buttonTint="@color/white"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Это [давно известная](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/507146/177345) "проблема". в ответе речь идет о `RecyclerView`, но тип виджета здесь не важен. Подробный ответ, [почему это происходит](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/520297/177345)

Comment: @pavlofff Спасибо!