# ListView и простой пример определения нажатого пункта

Tags: java, android, listview

Здравствуйте!
Брошу на лайоут ListView и Button
Набью на listView две строчки - "Москва", "Питер".
Как определить какая из них выбрана при нажатий на Button?
Просто в нете примеров много. Везде какие то классы и массивы используется. А мне надо простой пример без массива и класса.
Спасибо!

Comment: Код адаптера в студию.

Comment: А использование адаптера обязательна? Нельзя ли без него просто набить две строчки в дизайнере?

Comment: Нельзя. Только с ним. Он поставляет  данные для списка и представления его элементов.

Comment: Тогда для решения моей задачи использовать два TextView вместо одного ListView? И потом по событию onClick узнавать, которая из них нажался последним?

Comment: Возможно. Но я не понимаю, почему вам не нравится ListView c адаптером. Это азы азов.

Answer (score 7):

Попробуем разобраться в происходящем.

Есть класс `ListView`. Сам по себе `ListView` - это лишь наследник `View`, отвечающий за собственное отображение и манипулирующий отображениями переданных ему `View` (визуально отображающих элементы списка).

Подытожим абзац: `ListView` - это не сам список и списка никакого в себе не содержит, но содержит в себе адаптер, который ему передать должны Вы.

Есть класс `ArrayAdapter` или любой другой наследник `ListAdapter`, который отвечает за передачу `View`, отображающих элементы списка, в `ListView`.

Подытожим абзац: - `ArrayAdapter` - это не сам список, но это адаптер, содержащий в себе список, который передать ему должны Вы.

Есть класс `ArrayList` или любой другой наследник `List`, который является Вашим списком неких объектов.

А теперь долгожданный пример:

Создаём список:

```
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
stringList.add("Москва");
stringList.add("Питер");
```

Создаём простенький адаптер, передав ему список:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        getContext(), 
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
        stringList
);
```

Предполагается, что Вы уже знаете, как находить ресурсы в макете, так что ищем `ListView` и передаём ему адаптер:

```
final ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.list_view);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Что же после этого происходит под капотом? А происходит следующий диалог:

`ListView` говорит: Блин, пора уже отображаться! Адаптер, че за фигня? Где `View`? сколько их будет?

`ArrayAdapter` шарится в карманах, находит пачку `ArrayList` с мятным вкусом, смотрит количество объектов написанное на пачке мелким шрифтом и называет цифру..

`ListView` говорит: Давай уже первую, быстрее!

`ArrayAdapter` достаёт первый попавшийся объект по списку и рисует его отображение `View` по шаблончику, который мы ему передали, после чего говорит: держи Бро!

`ListView` берет отображение `View`, размещает его на экране поверх своего и говорит: Некогда объяснять, давай мне вторую!

И так, пока не наступит одно из двух событий:

1) кончилось место на экране;

2) кончилась пачка `ArrayList`;

После чего `ListView` и `ArrayAdapter` временно отдыхают, пока кто-то или что-то не начнёт скролить `ListView` или не скажет `ArrayAdapter`-у, что в пачке `ArrayList` что-то изменилось.

Ну а теперь думаю можно ответить на Ваш вопрос "как определить, какая строчка (пункт списка) была выбрана по нажатию на кнопку":

```
Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int selectedPosition = listView.getSelectedItemPosition();
        if (selectedPosition != AdapterView.INVALID_ROW_ID) {
            Toast.makeText(
                    context, 
                    "Выбран город " + stringList.get(selectedPosition),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Хотя есть способ и без кнопки при нажатии на сам элемент списка:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(
                context, 
                "Выбран город " + stringList.get(position),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        ).show();
    }
})
```

Comment: Интересный подход :) Вы случайно книги не пишете?

Comment: Еще [немного теории](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/491568/177345) по адаптерам в Android