# ListView не реагирует на нажатия

Tags: android, listview, listener

Есть список элементов. Хочу при нажатии на элемент списка выполнять какие-либо действия. Проблема в том, что слушатель почему-то не работает. Вообще нет никакой реакции и судя по логам, метод **onItemClick** не вызывается. Помогите разобраться в чем причина.

Вот код:

```
package ru.kulikovman.todolist;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import ru.kulikovman.todolist.adapters.GroupAdapter;
import ru.kulikovman.todolist.models.Group;

public class GroupList extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    DBHelper dbHelper;
    ListView groupListView;
    GroupAdapter groupAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_group_list);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
        groupAdapter = new GroupAdapter(this, dbHelper.getGroupList());

        groupListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.groupListView);
        groupListView.setAdapter(groupAdapter);

        groupListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        groupListView.setHapticFeedbackEnabled(true);
    }

    public void addGroup(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddGroupActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Log.d("myLog", "onItemClick");
        Group group = (Group) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        Toast.makeText(this, group.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Сам список выглядит вот так. В разметке элемента ничего особенного нет - TextView и ImageButton.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал делать через **OnItemLongClickListener**, но результат такой же - нажатия не обрабатываются. Еще прочитал что в разметке для кликабельных элементов нужно ставить *android:focusable="false"* - пробовал, не помогает. Других слушателей пересекающихся с этим вроде как нет.

Comment: Покажите адаптер. Вам скорее всего слушатель надо в адаптере непосредственно на вьюхи крепить. Вроде метод onItemClick работает только для системной разметки, на своей - не сработает

Comment: Добавил код адаптера.

Comment: Ну собственно в getView на view view и вешайте слушатель/прокидывайте интерфейс-слушатель нажатий

Comment: Попробуйтк еще `clickable`

Comment: Кстати у вас плохая структура. Для работы с БД передавайте курсор в адаптер и используйте `SimpleCursorAdapter`. Или как вы собираетесь после вставки данных в таблицу обновлять список? Снова получать все записи? Согласитесь, что проще вызвать `notifyDataSetChanged` и ребутнуть курсор. Вообщем, советую все таки задуматься о структуре пока не поздно (читай как мало кода) .P.S ОRM realm можно настроить на автообновлении и вообще не мучиться

Comment: @Flippy, можете дать ссылку на какой-нибудь пример с передачей курсора в адаптер. Я начинающий программист и другого способа пока даже не встречал. Делал как в туториалах.

Comment: Пожалуйста http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/111-urok-52-simplecursoradapter-primer-ispolzovanija.html

Comment: @Flippy, спасибо за ссылку. Разобрался с `SimpleCursorAdapter` - он работает только с `TextView` и `ImagesView`, которые определены в разметке. У меня немного сложнее. Это только группы, в задачах вообще куча параметров никак не связанных с разметкой. Поэтому текущий вариант похоже пока самый верный. `Clickable` пробовал, не помогает. Буду вешать слушатель на `view` или вообще через разметку.

Comment: Вы можете написать свой адаптер **любой сложности** унаследовавшись от `CursorAdapter`, чтобы использовать `Cursor` в качестве источника данных. То, что вы сейчас делаете - это детский сад, такое решение (перегонять данные из `Cursor` в какой то   `ArrayList` для того, чтобы показать их на экране) можно встретить только в малополезных "туториалах" из интернета, написанных так же малоквалифицированными авторами. Почитайте книгу Б.Харди "Android. Программирование для профессионалов", 2-е издание, там вы найдете множество полезной и правильной информации в формате разработки реальных приложений.

Comment: В как пример можете посмотреть [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/612783/177345) - никаких ограничений в реализации нет. Кстати, не совсем понятно, что вы имеете ввиду фразой "это только группы, в задачах вообще куча параметров никак не связанных с разметкой", но адаптер вовсе не предназначен для каких то задач,вовсе не связанных с разметкой (содержать какую-то бизнес-логику) - его назначение: [преобразовать данные в представление](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/491568/177345) на экране, все. Вам нужно ознакомиться с основами ООП, разделением ответственности и архитектуре приложений.

Comment: Автор, отпишитесь, как у вас дела обстоят? Помощь до сих пор нужна? В чем? Насчет `TextView` и `ImageView` - вы ошиблись, вы можете использовать любую разметку, это просто там в примере такая. Скорее всего вам нужен кастомный адаптер, так он станет намного гибче. Если все же есть проблемы - `RecyclerView` попроще и интуитивно понятнее. Почитайте лучше про него. Я вас прекрсно понимаю - сам в свое натерпелся со списками, это довольно сложненький элемент, но вы держитесь (:

Comment: @Flippy, спасибо за поддержку ). Проблема с OnItemClickListener решена, ниже написал что сделал для ее решения. Но учитывая комментарии выше... Скачал указанную pavlofff книгу, там есть RecyclerView и темы про списки, буду разбираться )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного подумал и решил, что **OnItemClickListener** слишком удобная штука, чтобы от него просто так отказываться. В итоге нашел целых *две проблемы*, которые не давали ему работать.

**Проблема 1**. В кастомном макете элементов списка все кликабельные элементы должны быть отключены. Для этого, пишем в корневом контейнере макета следующее:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

**Проблема 2**. По умолчанию элементы списка как-бы вообще отключены. Почему, непонятно. Для их включения, в классе адаптера нужно заоверайдить метод *isEnabled*, удалить из него обращение наверх и вернуть *true*. Выглядеть это будет так:

```
@Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

У меня не срабатывало, т.к. в текстовом поле кастромного списка стоял атрибут:

```
android:textIsSelectable="true"
```