# RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

Адаптер - создает все представления, отображаемые на экране и заполняет данными каждое представление , когда оно становится видимым. Что подразумевается под словом "представления"? Это один блок в списке RecyclerView, выделил красным. Или это view элементы, которые входят в один блок ?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Представления это в кривом переводе - View, то есть каждый виджет айтема (textview, imageview и тд), а так же и весь он целиком, так как контейнер, групирующий отдельные элементы, тоже View.

Простыми словами это то, что отображается на экране. Разобравшись с работой адаптера, в частности работой методов `onBindViewHolder()` (наполнение виджетов айтема контентом) и `onCreateViewHolder()` (инфлейт разметки айтема, создание визуального вида из xml-описания) не составит особого труда понять, что за представления имеются ввиду.

так же смотрите [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/491568/177345) по теории работы адаптера

Comment: Вот, это я и хотел услышать - контейнер, в который помещаются View элементы(TextView, ImageView и т.д.) называется ItemView или по другому ViewHolder. Спасибо!

Comment: нет. ViewHolder это класс-кэш, который хранит в себе только ссылки на каждое View в айтеме. Это не визуальный элемент, а грубо говоря, список, где эти визуальные элементы находятся, чтобы при необходимости к ним можно было быстро обратится.Такого "официального" понятия, как ItemView тоже нет, айтемом (Item) принято называть один пункт списка, то что обведено у вас красной рамкой, но это не класс в API, а просто устоявшееся выражение, в русскоязычной версии с таким же успехом этот элемент называют, например пунктом (списка)